# Moving the rows up and down on clicking the rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a container in which there are five rows with multiple columns. When you click on a row the entire row should move downwards so the first row should become the second row. I searched for this but what I found didn't work for me, could you point me to some articles or give me an idea to help me solve this.

Comment: Use a click event, and once a row is clicked, remove, and append it to it's sibling?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give us some code? What frameworks are you using?

Comment: please provide code

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that with jquery using click event and then get the previous or next row element and manipulating their indexes, using the index method present in jquery

[use the index method to get their position and then apply +1/-1 logic for changing the index](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: Could someone help me, I am new here, what else is to be added to the post to make it more readable for the OP